# How can i write a function which extracts the nth element of a list?

Tags: list, function, lisp, racket, cons

As part of my assignment i have been given the task to:

Write a function that takes two lists as input, a list L1 containing characters and a list L2
containing numbers. For each of the number n contained in L2, the function will display the first
n character of the list L1. For example:
L1 '("h" "e" "l" "l" "o" "w" "o" "r" "l" "d")
L2 '(2 3 1 5 10)
Output:
h e
h e l
h
h e l l o
h e l l o w o r l d.

i know the function takes two arguments but i don't know how to apply the second the list which is like a selector,it reads each number in the second list and extracts the character in that position in the first list.

```
( define two-sequences
( lambda ( l1 l2 )
(for/list ([ i l1 ] [ j l2 ])
```

which function should i use to do this.

Comment: A function which may be useful is `take`: eg `(take '(a b c d) 2)` => `'(a b)`

Comment: i mean the length of l2 is not specified because when i run the function,il have to enter 2 lists and  whatever number comes first in the second list,it will extract and so one until all the elements have been extracted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the first n elements of a list.  Here's how you do that:

To print the first `n` elements of a list, `lst`:

- if `n` is zero print a newline;
- if `n` is 1 print the first element of `lst` and a newline;
- if `n` is more than 1 print the first element of the `lst`, a space, and then print `n - 1` elements of the rest of `lst` (hint: you can use a function you are currently writing to do this);
- if `n` is anything else then this is an error.

Write this as a proceducre: call it `print-n` for instance.  Then the procedure which answers the question is:

```
(define (print-ns l ns)
  (for ([n (in-list ns)])
    (print-n l n)))
```

And

```
> (print-ns '("h" "e" "l" "l" "o" "w" "o" "r" "l" "d") '(2 3 1 5 10))
h e
h e l
h
h e l l o
h e l l o w o r l d
```

Comment: thanks,however,when i run the function it returns print-n: unbound identifier in: print-n

Answer (score 0):

In Common Lisp or emacs lisp this function you want is called `elt`
which gives the nth element of a list. - In Racket, you have to define it yourself:

```
(define (elt l n)
  (cond ((empty? l) '())
        ((zero? n) (car l))
        (else (elt (cdr l) (- n 1)))))
    
(elt '(a b c d e f) 3) ;;=> 'd
```

In every-day racket, however, one wouldn't use lists - which one has to traverse like this - but vectors - whose access via an index is direct and thus much more faster.

```
(vector-ref #("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f") 3) ;;=> "d"
```

`#(...)` is equal to `(vector ...)` and creates a vector out of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

> Write a function that takes two lists as input, a list L1 containing characters and a list L2 containing numbers. For each of the number n contained in L2, the function will display the first n character of the list L1.

The required function can be written compactly using `for/list`, but when learning Scheme/Racket it can be
helpful to build it with basic Scheme functions, without needing to know all the `for/xxxx` variations and options.

The problem can be split into two parts: (1) produce the characters to display (2) display them as shown in the question.
This answer will show the development of (1) using a [***systematic design method***](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UBCx+HtC1x+2T2017/77860a93562d40bda45e452ea064998b/#HtDF)
which can be applied to many problems like this.

##### (1) Start (in DrRacket) with the example data and a `require` for testing:

```
#lang racket
(require test-engine/racket-tests)

(define L1 '("h" "e" "l" "l" "o" "w" "o" "r" "l" "d"))
(define L2 '(2 3 1 5 10))

(test)
```

##### (2) Add a *stub* with *signature* and *purpose*, and a minimal *example*

```
#lang racket
(require test-engine/racket-tests)

(define L1 '("h" "e" "l" "l" "o" "w" "o" "r" "l" "d"))
(define L2 '(2 3 1 5 10))
                                                          ; *stub* ;; *signature*
(define (take-multiple los lon) ;; ListOfString ListOfNatural -> (ListOf ListOfString)
  ;; produce, for each n in lon, first n elements of los  ; *purpose statement*
  '() )                                                   ; *stub body* (valid result)
                                                          ;
(check-expect  (take-multiple L1 '())  '() )              ; *minimal example*

(test)
```

##### (3) Run: note that the test passes ("run early and often": make all tests pass)

(the function is named `take-multiple` because it "take"s initial elements from los multiple
times, according to the numbers in lon)

##### (4) Identify a *template* and *inventory* relevant to the requirement

`take-multiple` processes a list, so try the commonest template for that kind of argument, "natural recursion":

```
(define (fn lox) ;; ListOfX -> Y                  ; *template*: (for fn with list argument)
  ;; produce a Y from lox using natural recursion ;
  (cond                                           ;
    [(empty? lox) ... ]                           ; (...  = "base case value" ;; Y )
    [else (....                                   ; (.... = "inventory fn(s)" ;; X Y -> Y )
           (first lox) (fn (rest lox))) ]))       ;
                                                  ; *inventory fns*:
(take lox n) ;; ListOfX Natural -> ListOfX        ; (included because "...first n elements of los")
(cons x lox) ;; X ListOfX -> ListOfX              ; (included because required result is ListOf...)
```

##### (5) Edit the template by replacing the generic identifiers appropriately:

```
(define (take-multiple los lon) ;; ListOfString ListOfNatural -> (ListOf ListOfString)
  ;; produce, for each n in lon, first n elements of los
  (cond
    [(empty? lon) '() ]                           ; '() deduced from above check-expect
    [else (....
           (first lon) (take-multiple los (rest lon))) ]))
```

This won't run, because we don't know what to replace `....` with: to work this out

##### (6) Add the next simplest example:

```
(check-expect (take-multiple L1 '(2)) '( ("h" "e") ) )
```

So we require `(.... 2 (take-multiple L1 '()))` => `'( ("h" "e") ) )`
We can see that `(take-multiple L1 '())` is `'()`, and `("h" "e")` is `(take L1 2)`
so `(.... (first lon)` is `(cons (take los (first lon))`:

##### (7) Complete the code and add another example to check:

```
(define (take-multiple los lon) ;; ListOfString ListOfNatural -> (ListOf ListOfString)
  ;; produce, for each n in lon, first n elements of los
  (cond
    [(empty? lon) '() ]
    [else (cons (take los (first lon)) (take-multiple los (rest lon))) ]))

(check-expect (take-multiple L1 '(2 3)) '( ("h" "e") ("h" "e" "l") ) )
```

The first function is now complete (run `(take-multiple L1 L2)` to check).

To produce the required display format, use this function:

```
(define (display-elements lolox) ;; (ListOf (ListOfX)) ->
  ;; display elements of lolox with newlines between first level lists
  (for-each (lambda (lox)
              (for-each (lambda (x)
                          (display x) (display " "))
                        lox)
              (newline))
            lolox))
```

So `(display-elements (take-multiple L1 L2))` displays:

```
h e 
h e l 
h 
h e l l o 
h e l l o w o r l d 
>
```

Comment: A solution using `for/list` is: 
`(void (for/list ([i L2]) (for-each (lambda (s) (display s) (display " ")) (take L1 i)) (newline)))`